# ASP.NET Gridview with Link button column on Dynamic Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

ASP.NET Gridview with Link button column on Dynamic Grid

The ASP.NET Gridview should have a linked column - 1st column, when clicked should take to another page with the clicked cell value. the Grid is a dynamic one, that is the columns are not fixed, no of columns/ column itself is dynamic. I added a asp control just for the first columns and remaining columns are dynamic, in the code behind and I add the first column "linkbutton" always.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="linkbutton">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton" runat="server" Text='<%#EVal("linkbutton") %>'
            CommandName="ShowDetails" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("linkbutton") %>'>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField> 
</Columns>
```

linkbutton is part of the datatable, so when I bind the datatable to gridview it appears twice, once for the templatefield and once from the datatable bind. gridview.column().visible=false didnot work as it considers  linkbutton as the only column not the datatable columns.

i tried to add the Linkbutton control from code behind that one also didnt work.

Comment: Do you have autogeneratecolumns set to true on the GridView?

Comment: yes..the autogenerated columns is set to true

Comment: Will you show your code behind? If the gridview is dynamic why do you have autogenerated columns?

Comment: the code behind is simple, get the datatable and bind it.                      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                
                dt = ProductDB.GetProductList("1");

                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 1):

I would set the autogeneratecolumns to false, and then use asp:BoundFields in order to show the columns from the datatable, other than the linkbutton, which you are handling with the asp:TemplateField.

You can then use GridView.Columns().Visible to hide/show different columns.

You were not able to use GridView.Columns().Visible with the auto generated columns because [they are not added to Columns()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx):

> Explicitly declared column fields can be used in combination with
>   automatically generated column fields. When both are used, explicitly
>   declared column fields are rendered first, followed by the
>   automatically generated column fields. Automatically generated column
>   fields are not added to the Columns collection.

Comment: assume i got 100 columns and 50 columns only displayed and which 50 columns is unknown, but the columns 1 is always same, which is linkbutton.

Comment: Will you always have 100 columns? How will the 50 columns that will show up be determined?

Comment: 50 columns are determined by user preference